# Laravel : Validate Two Columns within One Table whist Checking for Unique Values

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, multiple-columns

I am working on a project where I have a table which has an inserttype_id column and a cate_id column.

We need to validate if the inserttype_id already has the same value (number) associated with it existing within the cate_id.

Then.. if the inserttype_id and cate_id exists together when validating, dont  go ahead an create the new database entry.

If does exist, then output a message "already exists"
if does not exist then create the entry

We started here, have tried so many examples and suggested solutions, but nothing will work for us.

```
$rules=['insertType_title'=>'required|unique:insertType',];
```

Any ideas with what needs to be changed here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
// add your category id variable I have used $cate_id
'inserttype_id'=>'required|unique:insertType,inserttype_id,NULL,inserttype_id,cate_id'.$cate_id
```

Comment: Trialing now, will reply asap

Comment: If you using laravel version 5.5 refer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique)